# Reading from text a file in a USB device.(C++/Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

`

```
texttobecopied = open('mtp://%5Busb%3A001,015%5D/Internal%20stora/AppInventor/data/Scan_result.txt', 'r').readlines()

//opening the text file which I want to read. This is located in the USB tethered smartphone. The mtp://.... part is the path for that file.

appendFile  = open('destinationFile.txt', 'a')

//opened the destination file into which I want to write.
appendfile.write('\n')
appendFile.write(texttobecopied)

//tried to write that text from source file into my destination file .

appendFile.close()
```

Beginner here.

I need a program that reads text from a `.txt` file located in my USB tethered phone(Internal storage) and writes that text in a file on my system.

I tried the conventional way by specifying the path (the traditional `object.open('path/name'.'r')` way) but it didn't work.

Is there a way I can do that? I do not wish to copy the file containing the text, I just need the text inside.

Comment: Not much of this makes any sense. Perhaps it would in context, but there isn't much of that either.

Comment: I have a smartphone connected to my system. I need a program that reads stuff from a `.txt` file located in the smartphone's internal storage and writes the same stuff on another `.txt` file located on my desktop. I hope that cleared something.

Comment: `$ mount /dev/sdc1 ; cp /media/usb_drive/path/to/file.txt ./sub/directory/file.txt`

Comment: Sounds like a reiteration that adds no new information.

Comment: You said _"I tried the conventional way by specifying the path (the traditional object.open('path/name'.'r') way) but it didn't work."_ ፨ OK, if you want to help us to help you please show what exactly you have tried, i.e., the code, some code at least,that you have used and also the error messages that you have received, otherwise your question is going to be closed and you won't receive any help. ፨ Further, is this question a python question or a C++ question? Could you please make up your mind?

Comment: Please edit your question incorporating the error message and, if you feel like that, also provide some of the code you've used. And... is it python or C++ ?

Comment: To edit your post, just click [edit] <<< this link, and please remove your latest comments.

Comment: @gboffi thanks, I am new here, sorry for that.

Comment: It seems to me that the `mtp://....` part comes from some desktop environment stuff, of which the `open` primitive is ***absolutely*** not aware of...  also your code looks Pythonish but the comments are C++, what's the matter?

Comment: Is there a way I can copy the contents file from the USB tethered smartphone to my desktop using code?


I wrote the code in Python, but I really need a solution to this ASAP, and I am comfortable w/ C++ and Python3 both, that is why I wrote C++/Python3.

Comment: Is the answer I had posted unuseful? Are there any sides of the problem that still need clarification?

Answer (score 0):

It's the Gnome virtual file system daemon (`gvfsd`) that works behind your back...

First, the phone's file system has to be mounted somewhere, it's not in the usual places (`/mnt/`, `/media/`) but it'd be registered in `/etc/mtab`, shouldn't it?

In my case it's at the end, and it's mounted in a runtime directory named against my `UID`,

```
$ grep "/$UID/" /etc/mtab
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

At this point I know the mount point in the computer file system of the phone file system and I can list its content

```
$ ls /run/user/1000/gvfs
'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D'/
```

I know the contents of *my* phone so that I can open, using Python, one of the files on my device

```
$ python -c "open('/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D/Internal shared storage/Ringtones/08_River.mp3', 'rb')"
$
```

As you can see, no errors opening the file.

I hope that you can adapt this recipe to your specific situation and accept my answer.